# Can't get WCF Host configuration to a client with adding Service Reference

Tags: wcf, configuration, default, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

I prepared a wcf service host and configured with some binding information below.

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpEndpoint>
  </standardEndpoints>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="NetTcpBinding" closeTimeout="00:02:00" openTimeout="00:02:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00" transactionFlow="true"
      transferMode="Buffered" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
      <transport protectionLevel="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="tcpServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="tcpServiceBehavior" name="MyClass">
    <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding" contract="IMyClass">
      <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/MyClass" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And instantiate with the code below:

```cs
ServiceHost wcfHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyClass));
wcfHost.Open();
```

Using QuickWatch checked it out and verified the configuration values. Then, I added Service Reference on "net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/MyClass" to an other project. So, the new config file below has been created in the client project.

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IMyClass" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
        transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
               maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
               maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
          <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/MyClass" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IMyClass" contract="IMyClass" name="NetTcpBinding_IMyClass">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The problem is the binding configuration of host can't come to client. If I change client configuration it doesn't affects. For example, changed *maxStringContentLength* value from *8192* to *2147483647*, then, saw that client has been instantiated with correct config but, operated with old config. Searched "*8192*" in solution and found in *.svcinfo* files as XML scheme. How can I solve this weird situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the service reference and "Update" the it and VS will regenerate the svcinfo files, or you could avoid this issue entirely by not using VS to create the service proxy and instead generating your own service proxy by hand (considered a best practice as far as I know).  As you already noted, "Add Service Reference" is not smart enough to take all those configuration values from the service when creating a client.